# Add class for parent if child has class active

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add class to the parent if the child has class `active`.
This is what I have done:

```
<ul class="grid-tab nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="active"></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class=""></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class=""></a></li>
</ul>

if ($(".grid-tab li a").hasClass("active")){
   $(".grid-tab li").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work:

```
<ul class="grid-tab nav nav-tabs">
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="active"></a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class=""></a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

```
$('.grid-tab > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $(this).closest('.grid-tab > li').toggleClass('active-li')
   .siblings('.grid-tab > li').removeClass('active-li');
});
```

Comment: I have to downvote your own answer since it does not really answer your question as stated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
$(".grid-tab > li > a").click(function(){
  $(".grid-tab > li").removeClass('active');
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).parent().addClass('active')
  }
});
```

```css
.active{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="grid-tab nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="active">A</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="active">B</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="active">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This <li> list is tab toggle when i click on link ,active class stay just for 1st parent ,

Comment: @mortezaYung, from your question you just mentioned to add class `active` to parent if the child has class `active`.

Comment: @mortezaYung, I have updated the answer to add class on clicking `a`...thanks.

Comment: It dosn't work,when i click on another <a> link that get class(active) so i want parent get class(active) too,and a priori <a> link that lose class(active) so i want parent lose class(active) too.

Comment: @mortezaYung, It is not clear to me what actually your requirement is? Currently, it will only add `active ` class to the parent of clicked `a`.

Comment: http://towndl.epizy.com/html

Comment: @mortezaYung, what to do with the link?

Comment: this does not even use event delegation and has 2 upvotes WOW

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me.

```
jQuery(this).parent('.active').addClass('yourClass');
```

Comment: this will only work if the parent also has the `.active` class - won't it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty simple, select those with the active class, then set the parent adding the `active` class.  I added a class css to the li just to show it working.  Other answers have click handlers etc but that is/was NOT in the question.

```js
$(".grid-tab li a.active").parent("li").addClass("active");
```

```css
li.active{border:lime solid 1px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="grid-tab nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="active"></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class=""></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class=""></a></li>
</ul>
```